# JDBC connection (java to oracle) connection issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to extract values from java to a table in Oracle but I'm encountering the following issue:

**error:**

```
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
> com.example.example1.query.demo.QueryDataNoPayload.lambda$1(QueryDataNoPayload.java:168)
>   at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)   at
> com.example.example1.query.demo.QueryDataNoPayload.main(QueryDataNoPayload.java:94)
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
```

**the code I am using is the following**

```
result.forEach(record -> 
          {
              String xml = record.getPayload().get();

              Summary summary = SUMMARIZER.summarize(xml);

              String a1 = (String) summary.getFields().get("gs") ;
              String a2 = (String) summary.getFields().get("dsf");
              String a3 = (String) summary.getFields().get("asOfDate");

              //Loading and registering Oracle database thin driver                
                try {
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    //Creating a connection between Java program and Oracle database.
                    Connection con;
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Classified details");
                    //Creating a Statement object to excute SQL statements 
                    Statement sql= con.createStatement();
                    //Executing a SQL INSERT query using executeUpdate()  method of Statement object.
                    sql.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO  example__DATA.Execution VALUES("+"'"+a1+"'"+","+"'"+a2+"'"+","+"'"+a3+"'"+")");

                }
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Please help me to understand what's wrong?

Comment: I couldn't understand why are you trying to connection inside in a for loop ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly add the Oracle lib JAR in the classpath ?

Maybe try with "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" if you added the jar correctly in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

The above line from the error says that the mentioned Class is not found.

Kindly check that you have the ojdbc jar present in your JVM ClassPath. Preferably `ojdbc6.jar`

Also there are 2 Driver Classes Present in the ojdbc jar

```
- oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
- oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Code will work for both of these.